# passing session variable to login page returns no session variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I'm setting `$_SESSION['url'] = "http://example.com" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` in a static page. My goal is to redirect back to this page upon successful login.

My login page:

```
        if($user->access_level=='Admin'){

        if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) {
            $myurl = $_SESSION['url']; 
        }
        else{
            $myurl = $home_url . "admin/index.php?action=login_success";
        }

    header("Location: {$myurl}");
    }
    else{
        header("Location: {$home_url}index.php?action=login_success");
    }
```

The `$_SESSION['url']` doesn't exist in the login page - verified with `var_dump($_SESSION);`

I am using the following .htaccess file in the dir with the login page, however the static page is two levels above the login dir.

.htaccess:

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews

# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/projects/php-login-system/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# used for php pages such as "yoursite.com/login.php" will become "yoursite.com/login/"
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of the page?

Comment: Don't do this via the session. If the user opens multiple different pages of your site in different tabs, it likely won't work any more on most of those pages. Put the info into a hidden form field - that way, you have the _correct_ address to redirect back to no matter which form the user submits. Or, simply send the form to the current page URL directly - easy enough to handle if you include a script on top of each page that checks whether login data was send via POST, and if so performs the necessary checks right then and there.

Comment: session_start() is in another include file at the top prior to the session. - I'm not disagreeing with your recommendation, I will look at that as well, however I still need to resolve why a session variable is not passing to another page?

Comment: actually the hidden field will not work, the static page is redirecting if the user is not authenticated, there is no post from that page.

Comment: Why redirect? User not authenticated - output login form only. User authenticated - show content.

Comment: Login form is on different page.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I had session_start() at the top of various include file in my page. This was resetting the session data after it was loaded but before it was redirected. The fix was to change the top of all pages to:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

$_SESSION['url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you don't have 
session_start();

at the top of your pages

Comment: session_start() is in another include at the top.

Comment: is it included in both the static and the login page?

Comment: yes since the same include file is needed in static and login page, I'm not sure if thats the problem or a workaround? any chance the .httaccess is causing the problem?